# Layout (Page) Deep Copy in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, hook

Currently when you copy a page, only the page itself is copied, not the content on the page. So you get identical portlets on the new page, configured to show the same content, but the content itself is just a reference to the same content. Could we create the ability to clone pages? In 6.2 we can only copy pages which uses the same web content, which defeats the purpose in most cases. The idea is to be able to copy a page that has the same content with new web content id's and a new page.

Please see the actual requirement [here](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Proposals/Layout+%28Page%29%20Deep+Copy). It is the GSoc propsal of Liferay for the year 2015.

Comment: Stackoverflow is the wrong place for feature requests - use https://issues.liferay.com instead. If you wanted to ask how to clone the content - there is already a question regarding that: [Duplicating a Liferay web page with non referenced web contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116420/duplicating-a-liferay-web-page-with-non-referenced-web-contents)

Comment: I got the requirement from here https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Proposals/Layout+%28Page%29%20Deep+Copy. And created a issue here https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-60242.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that Liferay offers through the UI is implemented through the use of Liferay's API. If Liferay's "copy page" does not meet what you want to achieve, you're able to implement this for yourself - however, note that Liferay might not have deep knowledge about the content of various portlets, thus a deep copy will never be totally consistent: What with a portlet that shows customer data - do you want to duplicate that customer when you deep-copy a page?

For this reason I'd agree that the current copy might not do what *you* expect from copying web content. But it does the only thing that can be implemented consistently. And the rest is open to your extension. Tobias Liefke has posted the pointer to entering feature requests in his comment.

Comment: And even for web content it is difficult to decide which parts to clone in a page. For example if there are additional _teasers_ on a page - which you usually don't want to clone when copying a page.

Comment: Not to forget images - either embedded in content or shown otherwise. The concept of a "deep copy" is one of those easy to ask for but hard to describe in a bulletproof way. Showing a folder in doclib? Copy it?

Comment: I have developed a hook to clone pages (deep copy of the layout with cloning web contents, images and meta information). The requirement is a Liferay GSOC proposal for 2015 (https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Proposals/Layout+%28Page%29%20Deep+Copy). What I did is while copying the pages I copy the web content articles and meta data of a portlet  and updated the portlet preferences with newly cloned information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

I have found solution for this particular situation where you want the clone of the web content which doesn't change that original page web content if you change the content in web content display portlet on cloned page.

I have done it through ext,

Create a ext plugin and then copy the below file,It contains the changes which will need to copy the web content as well.Deploy this ext and clone the page again. You have to override "**EditLayoutsAction.java**" (package is com.liferay.portlet.layoutsadmin.action) file which contains the clone logic.

In updateLayout(actionRequest, actionResponse) method find below code

```
if (copyLayout != null) {
                if (copyLayout.isTypePortlet()) {
                    ActionUtil.copyPreferences(
                        actionRequest, layout, copyLayout);
```

Copy below code under found code

```
long companyId = themeDisplay.getCompanyId();
                    long ownerId = PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_ID_DEFAULT;
                    int ownerType = PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_TYPE_LAYOUT;

                    for (String portletId : portletllist) {

                        if(portletId.startsWith("56_INSTANCE"))
                        {

                            javax.portlet.PortletPreferences  prefs = PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getPreferences(companyId,
                                    ownerId,
                                    ownerType,
                                    copyLayout.getPlid(),
                                    portletId);

                            String articleId = prefs.getValue("articleId", "1234");

                            if(!(articleId.equalsIgnoreCase("1234"))){

                            JournalArticle jArticle=JournalArticleServiceUtil.copyArticle(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), articleId, "0", true, Double.parseDouble("1"));


                            javax.portlet.PortletPreferences  newPrefs = PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getPreferences(companyId,
                                    ownerId,
                                    ownerType,
                                    layout.getPlid(),
                                    portletId);

                            newPrefs.setValue("articleId", jArticle.getArticleId());


                            PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.updatePreferences(ownerId, ownerType, layout.getPlid(), portletId , newPrefs);
```

Then create ext and deploy it and follow the same clone process but now this time it will generate copy of the article so changes to cloned web content will not be reflected to original page.